# Playframework DynamicForm always null values

Tags: java, forms, playframework, null

I have a HTML form and want to process it through my Controller. But if I want to access a field and for example Log it or print it out, it always gives me a null value

Does someone know why?

Controller:

```
public static Result register() {
    DynamicForm users = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
    Logger.info(users.get("vorname"));
    return ok("hallo " + users.get("vorname"));
}
```

View:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="@routes.Signup.register()" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="vorname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vorname</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vorname" placeholder="Vorname">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nachname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nachname</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nachname" placeholder="Nachname">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email-Adresse</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email-Adresse">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passwort</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Passwort">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rpassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Passwort wiederholen</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="rpassword" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="geschlecht" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Geschlecht</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <select class="form-control" id="geschlecht">
                        <option>Männlich</option>
                        <option>Weiblich</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Registrieren</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
 DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm().bindFromRequest();
```

I also encourage you to use form helpers just to make sure that everything is configured properly.
https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaFormHelpers

Edit. Yes, you should use definitely use helpers. You forgot to put "name" attribute in your vorname input. This attribute, not id is essential in handling forms.